# Issue with computed column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

In my table, I have 2 columns. One is `CheckNo` and of type `varchar(10)`. A check number or text can be entered into this column. Example of texts is `EFTPS` (electronic funds transfer) or `RT CHK` (returned check).

I also have a computed column called `CheckNumber` which currently is populated with the following formula:

```
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([CheckNo]) > (0) THEN [CheckNo] END)
```

This populates column `CheckNumber` with the check number that appears in `CheckNo`.

My issue is that I need the returned check number to be in a numeric data type. I have tried a number of edits to the base formula to get this to happen but I always get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I have tried:

```
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([CheckNo]) > (0) THEN CAST([CheckNo] AS numeric) END)

(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([CheckNo]) = (1) THEN CONVERT([decimal](18, 0), [CheckNo]) ELSE (0) END)

(CONVERT([numeric](18, 0), CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([CheckNo]) = (1) THEN [CheckNo] END))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a notorious function that does not do what you think / want. Simple searching will find discussions about why this does not work.

Comment: Something seems suspect in *needing* check numbers to be treated as numeric. It's not like e.g. adding two check numbers together, or taking an average, etc makes sense. They're in that class of "numbers" where often the most sensible data type to use for them *is* string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TRY_CAST; designed for such purposes:

```
TRY_CAST([CheckNo] as numeric)
```

It will return NULL if not convertible to a number.